# Processing a command as having no horizontal or vertical space

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to process `\marginpar{<arguments>}` as taking up no space in the body text? Right now I end up with a really ugly white line.

I am aware of the `marginnote` package, but this also takes up space in the body text and messes with the page layout.

See the image:

[image: Ugly white line]

Or a [link (if the picture is rescaled too small)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apsNJ.png).

code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}       
\subsubsection{Section}

Je kunt ook meerdere getallen (rijen of lijsten) toekennen aan \'e\'en object. Dit is handig als je met \textbf{\textit{data sets}}\hypertarget{document.dataset}{}\marginpar[]{\hyperlink{begrippen.dataset}{\textit{Data set}}}, \textit{verzamelingen}, enzovoort, werkt. Behalve verzamelingen van specifieke getallen, kun je ook een rij van gehele getallen maken (gehele getallen zijn van het soort $Z = \ldots,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$). 
\hypertarget{document.rcommand.c}{}\marginpar[]{\hyperlink{appendix.rcommand.c}{\texttt{c()}}}\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}   
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A picture containing the code is useless.

Comment: @egreg You don't think the question is conceptual in a way where an MWE would serve (comparatively) little purpose?

Comment: The code is essential for trying to reproduce the problem and suggest workarounds. I'm certainly not going to retype it.

Comment: @egreg added the code because you made a funny

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is that your `\marginpar` is coming right at the end of a line at the end of a paragraph where the next thing is an environment that needs to add at least some vertical space.  I bet if you moved your `\marginbox{...c()}` to after `het soort`, the problem would disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your commands `\target` as well as `\marginbox` produce something "substantial" in the current paragraph (though it has no size).

Try

```
foo bar \hypertarget{}{} baz.
```

You will observe a "double" space between the last two words caused by the target.

In your case, the magic stuff gets shoved into the next line after the end-of line space space in

```
Je kunt ook meerdere getallen (rijen of lijsten) toekennen aan \'e\'en object. Dit is handig als je met \textbf{\textit{data sets}}\target{document.dataset}\marginbox{begrippen.dataset}{\textit{Data set}}, \textit{verzamelingen}, enzovoort, werkt. Behalve verzamelingen van specifieke getallen, kun je ook een rij van gehele getallen maken (gehele getallen zijn van het soort $\mathbb{Z} = \ldots,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$). 
\target{document.rcommand.c}\marginbox{appendix.rcommand.c}{\texttt{c()}}\begin{Rcode}
```

This will produce an empty line even without the `\marginbox{appendix.rcommand.c}{\texttt{c()}}`!

The solution is to put a `%` here:

```
Je kunt ook meerdere getallen (rijen of lijsten) toekennen aan \'e\'en object. Dit is handig als je met \textbf{\textit{data sets}}\target{document.dataset}\marginbox{begrippen.dataset}{\textit{Data set}}, \textit{verzamelingen}, enzovoort, werkt. Behalve verzamelingen van specifieke getallen, kun je ook een rij van gehele getallen maken (gehele getallen zijn van het soort $\mathbb{Z} = \ldots,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$).% 
\target{document.rcommand.c}\marginbox{appendix.rcommand.c}{\texttt{c()}}\begin{Rcode}
```